# How can this assembly program print "Hello World"?

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.data
.global _start
_start:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #12
    ldr r4, =#0x6c6c6548
    str r4, [pc, #4]
    mov r1, pc
    add pc, pc, #8
    strbt r6, [ip], -r8, asr #10
    svcvs 0x0057206f
    beq 0x193b248
    swi #0
    mov r7, #1
    mov r0, #0
    swi #0
```

I stumbled upon this little ARM assembly program, which prints "Hello World". Save it as `test.s` to test:

```
$ as -o test.o test.s
$ ld -o test test.o
$ ./test
Hello World
$
```

How does this work? I cannot see a single string in the entire program. It also doesn't read the string from anywhere else; it looks like this code is all that's needed to print the string. Where does the string come from?

Comment: Oh, yeah. If I did it correctly, it should be be "lleH" (which is backwards?). Where's the rest? The second hexadecimal constant would contain a 0 byte, and the third one looks even more weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an annotation of the interesting bit:

```
  mov r7, #4
  mov r0, #1
  mov r2, #12
  ldr r4, =#0x6c6c6548
A str r4, [pc, #4]
B mov r1, pc
C add pc, pc, #8
D strbt r6, [ip], -r8, asr #10
E svcvs 0x0057206f
F beq 0x193b248
G swi #0
  mov r7, #1
  mov r0, #0
  swi #0
```

The store at `A` is targeting location `D` - as pointed out in the comments, that word (in little endian order) creates the 4 ASCII bytes "Hell" - that gets stored over the top of the nonsensical instruction there (the machine code of which is 0xe66c6548 - close, but not good enough). That's presumably also why this is in the data section, to ensure that it is writeable<sup>*</sup>. Meanwhile, the machine code of the instruction at `E` is 0x6f57206f, which makes "o Wo". Instruction `F` is particularly tricksy, as that address must result in the relative branch offset, once encoded, looking like "rld"<sup>**</sup> - the `beq` encoding is 0x0annnnnn, where nnnnnn is the top 24 bits of a 26-bit two's complement offset value - note also that the condition code and opcode in the top byte there make up the final newline.

Instruction `B` puts the address of `D` into r1, i.e. a pointer to the start of the string. r0 and r2 are obviously the other necessary syscall arguments, and r7 is the syscall number itself (I'm too lazy to look it up, but I assume the 1 in r0 is for stdout, the 12 in r2 is the number of characters, and syscall 4 is `write`).

Finally, instruction `C` is a jump to the syscall at `G`, so none of the "instructions" at `D`, `E`, and `F` are actually executed (the rest after that is just making an `exit` syscall).

Pretty neat, for trick code.

<sub>* and presumably also relying on some backwards-compatibility behaviour in the loader to leave the data section executable.</sub>

<sub>** which incidentally doesn't happen with my binutils 2.26 linker, probably due to the default section alignment having changed in recent versions.</sub>

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that the instructions themselves contain the string when assembled? That's pretty cool. How do they know what instructions they need to use to generate the correct string? Also, why is instruction A necessary? Couldn't they just use another instruction that generates the correct part of the string?

Comment: @user6571836 In ARM that's the norm. See what a [literal pool](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473f/Bgbccbdi.html) is. The code fragment seed to be a partially successful disassembly.

Comment: @user6571836 You can either sift through the instruction encoding index finding those where the opcode bits match the data you want, then craft operands to suit the rest, or do the inverse of just forcing the desired data through a disassembler to see what you get (and if you're unlucky in either case, then working out how to patch it up). Having just tried the latter, it turns out 0x6c6c6548 _is_ actually a valid instruction encoding - I get some crazy mnemonic for an obscure and obsolete FPU, but it could also be decoded back to a generic `stc` instruction if one really cared.